# having trouble with TI-83+ z80 hex program

Tags: assembly, hex, z80

I made an AsmProgram that runs this hex code:

```
9D95:00
9D96:00
9D97:00
9D98:00
9D99:0E
9D9A:09
9D9B:3E
9D9C:00
9D9D:EF
9D9E:5D
9D9F:49
9DA0:06
9DA1:80
9DA2:A8
9DA3:CB
9DA4:47
9DA5:CB
9DA6:0F
9DA7:CA
9DA8:95
9DA9:9D
9DAA:10
9DAB:F9
9DAC:C9
```

it's supposed to wait until the + button is pressed then end, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: What is this hex dump supposed to do? It does not look like Z80 machine code.

Comment: @RadLexus looks like <address>:<byte> pairs. Don't remember `AsmPrgm` allowing addresses though.

Comment: @Ilja: yes I realize that. But the code part of this hex dump does not look like Z80 code. Even if it is: are we supposed to disassemble this ourself, while the OP *has* the correct assembly somewhere? (Surely?)

Comment: @RadLexus sorry for being patronizing. And yeah, it's ugly leaving the disassembly for the readers.

Comment: i do not have the actual assembly code. i programmed it in hex. it should do something like

1:nop x 4
2:ld c,09
3:ld a,00
4:call(b_GetKey)
5:ld b,80
6:xor b
7:bit 0,a
8:rrc a
9:jp z,9D95
10:djnz -3
11:ret

Comment: Got the same through disassembly, except you've got the jp z, 9d95 messed up in the original, currently it's going to 959d. Little endianness.

Comment: i changed it, and it does nothing different. it just runs and completes in a split second, ignoring any input.

Comment: Didn't say it'd work. Your key code checking is rather complex.

Comment: You call DispTail. GetKey is 4972. Other than that, the code is plain weird.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is your original code, as far as I can tell:

```
        .org 9D95h
        nop
        nop
        nop
        nop
        ld c, 09h       ; ???
        ld a, 0         ; ???
        rst 28h         ; \
        .db 5Dh         ;  > DispTail, destroys AF, BC, DE, HL, aka
        .db 49H         ; /  undefined behaviour in this case (we don't
                        ;    know what A contains)
        ld b, 80h       ; B <- 0x80
        xor b           ; A <- A XOR B
        bit 0, a        ; A[0] == 0, Z is set, if so
loop:   rrc a           ; rotate right A, C <- A[0]
        jp z, 9D95h     ; Jump to 9D95, if Z set
        djnz loop       ; Decrease B, jump if not zero to loop
        ret             ; After 128 jumps, returns
```

So all in all, they key code checking part was incorrect from the get go (calling the wrong ROM call and overly convoluted). Here's what seemed to work:

```
        .org 9D95h
        rst 28h         ; \
        .db 72h         ;  > Call GetKey, A <- key code
        .db 49h         ; /
        cp 80h          ; Compare A with immediate value 0x80 (subtract),
                        ; key code for [+] is 0x80
        jp nz, 9D95h    ; Jump if Z is not set (was not 0x80)
        ret             ; return
```

or in hex:

```
EF 72 49 FE 80 C2 95 9D C9
```

Comment: i've been using a b_call chart that i guess is only meant for the ti-84 so getkey was replaced with disptail. where is a good b_call hex list for ti-83?

Comment: Found http://wikiti.brandonw.net/index.php?title=83Plus:BCALLs:4972, though it's for the 83+.

Answer (score 2):

The program you wrote is essentially for the TI-83+/84+/SE model calculators. Your intended target was for the TI-83. There are three main things you need to change:

- Start your code at .org $9327, not $9D95
- There are no bcall()s just system calls. Instead of bcall(_GetCSC) you would do call _GetCSC
- You need ti83asm.inc instead of ti83plus.inc

So with all that, let's make an example program:

```
.NOLIST
#define equ .equ
#define EQU .equ
#define end .end
#include "ti83asm.inc"
#include "tokens.inc"
.LIST
.org 9327h
start:
    call _GetKey ;CDFE4C
    cp 80h       ;FE80
    jr nz,start  ;20F9
    ret          ;C9
```

I've never programmed for the TI-83, so I hope from the tutorials I read that I pieced together working code.